# how to remove INFO.console logs from vs studio ide when running selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, logging, visual-studio-code

I only need to see what my prints output in the terminal. Logs clutter the screen:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59844/devtools/browser/9c6d16aa-c1da-4e4e-88c3-619a6377616d

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59859/devtools/browser/5868a5b2-3eb1-4d2e-aec4-d97cbb858069
[0722/142212.508:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(122)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer.
[0722/142215.435:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "A preload for 'https://yastatic.net/pcode-bundles/0.1788/banners.js' is found, but is not used because the request credentials mode does not match. Consider taking a look at crossorigin attribute.", source: https://tengrinews.kz/js/loader.js?v=268 (3)
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59903/devtools/browser/3947b095-cfc8-49b9-b6b4-2702fe02fe6e
[0722/142220.093:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(122)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer.
[0722/142223.038:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "A preload for 'https://yastatic.net/pcode-bundles/0.1788/banners.js' is found, but is not used because the request credentials mode does not match. Consider taking a look at crossorigin attribute.", source: https://tengrinews.kz/js/loader.js?v=268 (3)
```

Answer (score 0):

To suppress some of the *Console* logs you can import the `warnings` module and add a line as:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Comment: @ERJAN Time to time I use it on my _windows_ localhost as well and it works as expected.